# Sharepoint external fields names

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, field, csom

We already know how to get the internal field names in a SharePoint list. But I have been having to manually look at the list on the sharePoint site, and then compare it to a printed list of the internal field names, to figure out which external, shown name corresponds to which internal name. 
Is there any way, using the SharePoint client object model or otherwise, to directly find external field names based on a given internal field name, or vis versa?

Comment: Well you could always use the .NET Connector for SharePoint and use SHOW COLUMNS http://www.bendsoft.com/documentation/camelot-net-connector/latest/sql-statement-syntax/show-columns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it's "item.DisplayName" where "item" is the actual name of an item. Or, if you want it for a field instead of an item, use "field.Title" where "field" is the internal name of a field.